# ngrx angular actions and effects are not triggering

Tags: typescript, web, graphql, frontend, ngrx

Actions are not triggered in angular project knowing that this project is pulled from source control where everything is working 100 % but when try to develop a new features the actions are not triggered taking into consideration that all classes and functions are implemented as copy paste for old features with takin care of renaming for sure.

The project is implemented by angular and GraphQL as frontend and asp.net core with sql as backend

Comment: When you say "actions are not triggered", do you mean that calling `store.dispatch(MyAction)` doesn't do anything?

Comment: Most likely you haven't registrered the effect in the `EffectsModule` like `EffectsModule.forFeature([MyEffects])`.